# Oracle - Object no longer exists

Tags: oracle, object, exists

We have a daily partitioned table with retention of about 180 days.  We have created a view with a group by .., to_char(DATE_COL,'YYYYMM');
The users started to extract the data from the views for each month; and at one moment of executing the view for 201510, it had failed with "Object no longer exists" even though the view and the underlying table exists.

I am suspecting that Unix issued a new partition creation statement for the next day which is automated process(verified in data dictionary);

The question is if the query on the view is running, there would be read lock on the table, thereby the partition couldn't have been created as it needs exclusive lock;
If the view wasn't running, then the ALTER table statement to create partition would have been completed and then if there was any query on the view, it wouldn't have been failed.
Did the query on the view fired at almost the same time when alter table statement to add partition was being executed;  if so, as there is an exclusive lock on the table through alter table statement, the query on the view would have waited for read lock as currently there is exclusive lock.  Why did I see this error, can you please elucidate.

Comment: You keep mentioning "read lock". Oracle doesn't have such a thing. The reason why you get the error is because the table is being partitioned at precisely the point at which you try to read from it, and strange things can happen... as you've found out!